# How to coerce a function argument (object) have specific key pattern

Tags: typescript

I have a case where I need to make a function that accepts an object with specific keys, which hold specific values. Namely:

```
type ArgType = {
   name: string
   selectors: {
      [key: string]: Selector
   }
}
```

For the purpose of this example, a Selector is defined as a `<S>(state: S) => unknown`

However, I would like to coerce this selectors object to have a specific key pattern, namely the keys should follow the pattern of `select${Capitalize<string>}`, so when the function in question receives it's arguments, the argument must conform to this pattern, or in other words:

```
Foo( { 
   name: "Bar",
   selectors: {
      selectBuzz: () => {},
      fizz: () => {},
      selectFizz: '123',
   }
})
```

An object argument would report error for both "fizz" as it is missing the naming pattern of "selectFizz" as well as selectFizz as it is not a selector.

How would I do that?

Comment: Could you [edit] to fix the typos in your code?  You need commas after object properties.

Comment: There, I made the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since TypeScript 4.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures), so-called *pattern* [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)) can be used as the key type of an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  So you can do this:

```
type ArgType = {
  name: string,
  selectors: {
    [key: `select${Capitalize<string>}`]: Selector
  }
}    
type Selector = <S>(state: S) => unknown;    
declare function Foo(a: ArgType): void;
```

and it behaves as desired:

```
Foo({
  name: "Bar",
  selectors: {
    selectBuzz: () => { },
    fizz: () => { },  // not an error until you resolve the below error
    selectFizz: '123' // error
  }
})

Foo({
  name: "Bar",
  selectors: {
    selectBuzz: () => { },
    fizz: () => { }, // error    
    selectFizz: () => { }
  }
})

Foo({
  name: "Bar",
  selectors: {
    selectBuzz: () => { },
    selectFizz: () => { }
  }
}) // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwCrmgXigbwFBSgOwEMBbCALigGdg4BLfBAGlyogBsIBjYAezkoo48eANoBrCCAoADSuy7AAJJgDChMLWCE2tAF4QAPNToMAfAF9pAXQoBledz4tz2F9lCQo9jo7hQMBramABTUhMDkXgCU-qZQAK74Yvg8AO74ANzY2AAmXGyEcNAAZonctDz4UABiPDzBhBTwyKhRFABuPLQ5Wdi19UIEJJEARABChSPMeHI+vPyCLDMOwGPxuroUwTFocZhQ5tPCxXqbUNuxWAeMeAD0t1DAABa0lFCpPPFsOVAARtCEKoQOBwPh-eLAKCaKA5HgQSj4ADkkMoTzSCTACXwwFobCgIE+UCKlB4bHa0Ge0GBoL8-zYaSWrDm1VOFERAEYAEwAZkRUHuUGpTjwLnMUWy-WCgyIpAo40mR1mCj4AiwjKV3DWGy2Oz210ZJ21511V0O-IeQr8wnVKxZRouu1Nzlc4r6dSlLBlowmcCmLA181Vg2Wcy1ZwdesONuZrONl32LhFLuyQA)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work, but I am having issues implementing it into my "real" types where the Arg type uses a generic which is a tuple and the selectors's keys used to be `{ [I in keyof T]: Selector }`. How would we create a Mapped Type that uses this pattern?

Comment: I'd need to see a [mre] of the problem you're having, but if you have a followup question you might want to open a new post for it instead of discussing here, since comment sections aren't great places to work on stuff.

Comment: Alright I will post a new question with that and comment the link here in a few minutes

Comment: Here is the question posted as requested, I'd suggest using the TS playground as its more true to the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708236/how-to-remap-the-object-types-of-a-function-argument-to-produce-a-desired-type-s