# How to remap the object types of a function argument to produce a desired type shape

Tags: typescript

I am trying to resolve an issue with forcing a certain "pattern" in the framework, for the lack of a better word, that I am making. The framework in question is a form of Redux store composer (give or take).

The TS playground links:

1. The [full complex](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhGB7AkgO2BATgZwgGNgBLVTAHhiggA8dMATfKAQ0xAG0BdAPigBeKAG8AUFElQu6KKUxQA1hBCoAZrB4AuKAAo6OmDJ4BKIQIBuqUkzEBfLpjgBbAEZ4etBhGat9O+TU8KABVM0FLa1spKAB+UIkpHUwICzwxMVBIUMxyTDQsHAJiMgpKEIFhXRCvRhZ2Tji9RR0w8ygrGyhk1Lwzejq-RMkWuUwg3Ch0MXDIm2Gm6ZietNwM+SK1NiJoABEAUQAxdAA5fd2AfQBBAGEYdAB5E4uYAE0ABX2AZVEFgHIAAI3B4AJX2AHpTugYH8dHBMIpMKgAO6Yf5A0EQsHvAAyt32sKg8MRKLRMQAQlcYDcABLXO6PE5fHQidgkPL4HRXThXdkUXhQOwLbF4m77C5fGBU-YsqBgNggRCoNhMWVcZQgHT4YC4eQAc20RIRSNRgsF9gyWWgt3uTxeH2+QiUKnUUAOxzOlxtjPtny+62weC2OygvNKVBoAx89W9drefqdsee8e+AnEMSthgtmXA1r5mC+AAs2JBqJVYLVo6wk77HfEw3ky1AAGRuo6nc7023Jh1fLgwTwrdI57LckANiiJ-NFksQSg1lNfPiW3Nu0j4eXAIiF+eV3yhnn5xOH8Pl3TbcNc2YdKIr7IwQvEicKYTz3B6-B8XRMdeb7c6XZfzYLdCwAGlqXA2Cud9OVDGDr3eXBUGcdc5w4EBlxHPNwxuXAIGA1BJiqAA6Ui2BgnR0N4a8x2fKAAB9YEfBFnzvaAAFkbCYZBkXIud9gYY9x3zctKB+KN9y+YBCLQzg+C-BZtRknR-WvXQUgYACgJAtSLzyLkTzyBioAE4Br06Ww2KgL4IGQEhCLEp10PAkEnWJE1MDPbVgIgFTrxBLCoBBfD7NwRzhGcoK9xjQzJ2EWiRKdXRvJwPz2lcxinEQRArOCpg4B2MKlySlLfOs8C9IoAzhPDa9-UCkJMHwOBXHwIhdXcJLzNvMQNiDbZoCkmSxLTBY9QgYApJ8nRdDqhYfw3YD-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-dC6CIMhMAqB8DFyqonUGNwQFgIgVQM+15OI-x4nxS+C8P5LzwOA7UXIGRxl7LwA2mxMZ+wgDA5woDwHhmoAnKi-BfgxFcBHfOEBYKshkGMZ0qgNADkMMYLgAAGTwQpt65DIKXBmOBYLwCQCgDA-1CD5koBw2Q8huGuj4aIaQAApLhRh0A8CETwQ0BijEAEYRGCmXDXRuD0Z6yOQAURRJRGyqK4RqTRhoOF6PUWY4xhoPphX8ZYgQdhrEdx7oYBATiFFFCUTQ9x6jPG8NMQIgATCImxUhB4h2iXI5x8TXFlCSQoFJmh+GGK4AAZiyddPWkt8mxMKNg4pVBSkaNSZUoxAAWOpCxwTgjGPTdiE1CyoBYCyAZQzJCcOSS6LpeglJ4RUk-RB7QLLTPNDEQZ7AKKMKkLs2ZaiykLIqUsw+qzhrrIiLAARABWHgWzRGHKGd-X+fEpk7JmdIE5nTzlANgdQ-SUDkAUKofAssSCuKoLws8jIYiRljImewhY0s-nlK0boNFMQcmXJyHkQprTlFGA3u4XAFiGFhygC7d2JAcW4txfEY+c5GqEricSmhpKXDkspfJBljKkgL16GsQVUBvoLBeZIciH4vmCrmacnhAKBUD3xWyigRLigkscDyjwXBQkJ1pSUFVgrmVP3VfkDlWquU6s3hS-V-BslisZUOUVgrrz+MeZKhY7zYVlUhoyhV-ysXAMoXAy8oLyFAshTAc+7RkEfJPp6-g3qYjL1QDsfAhBVQHMDRis5WiyHUAEcI8CISeBloyRWu5VTamVqqX0+tRjHlOvNL9K0kasDF1VizIiUBTYxFYQnW2eoY6Px8oat2Hs049wTmQgODtR4EznRHKOksx0p0liupOm6CBjvTqHJ29QjX0oUjEYBgZsBysZTnS2OhWECs7vgW+4MBW5IJrfNdBABVTxDrfXd+ABXL3ILqUAt8yVb0FTvAByyj5PzLhAONtyLJQF2ffFZj9rkvw2beMVMrn0zVg1ck+CGkMCAPahoZ6G4NYYwq-DOYrfUQD-hAABoaIURrIeC8NjYbkCATX6oD2C9ovvwT2P0RCYjhNbNi51UhGIBrk1IHeJdEAIdWT5E1jLa72N1k3IqUjENae2UphTwyJFqcM+BkVABuKAOnCrWdWCZxlJgZjtCLaw8CCHwIB2sku9ds8Q6+ZgphMQTBiCID4lAC92oYtTxwGQnQZCu0WbVsOWLwBE5OnasjCAZDdCKdvWVAARAJC2ciSvgXfY03NuL5DANwHhEgVxso6HMek6pY6xGNea8AVhh12isjsN1nJS6sC9ZKDAXM7XOujckO+mBTWSitcQIN25w3vV2DcxkXZVxWDImgEQDgUBCDQGAIWaAFBEAgFoE1wi9mICgNwDgJgchWBqAexdo7bBCBQGRJdvCUBvtQBOFcdi+woDOCWpd1gIPNxFAUMwrLIOO1MFQGwzAfxgD212eo47f3XRsAXrnKH65ocgQqo0DteoMf4HAgD0g253sL1QCjy7YxGDAGIkxdcMWTuM3wKgKAnUzsKHUSDlCuRnAuEe+muubBXDIC8BV5Xn2QZQEB2VQswBgBgE5IM4AG4osgGIhFiw4JnBXD1AATgABzIiAA), all types included (this is the one I'd need, but its a doozy)
2. [Siplified](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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) (minimum reproducable example - showcasing the same issue)

The gist is as follows:

I have a function which is used to create a "bundle" or a plugin for the framework named "createBundle" this function is of the type `BundleInitializer` which is a complex type but suffice it to say that the return type of this functions is a `Bundle` type.

The goal is to allow developers to call a "createBundle" function, which would then have intelliSense support and allow for an easier adherence to the pattern that this function requires for the argument it recieves.

The `BundleInitializer` signature semantically is as follows (simplified for clarity):

```
type BundleInitializer = <
  Name extends string,
  Selectors extends Record<string, Selector>, //
>(
  content: {
    name: Name
    selectors: Selectors
  }
) => Bundle<Name, Selectors>
```

Where the type of a selector is (again for the sake of simplicity) `Selector = () => unknown`. This would then allow us to pass an argument that is shaped like such:

```
const arg = {
   name: "Example",
   selectors: {
      foo: () => {},
      bar: () => {}
   }
}
```

But my goal is to enforce the naming of selectors to follow a pattern of `select${Capitalize<string>}`. So I tried to use the following types to achieve that (the types that follow are all in the "simplified" version of the TS playground link):

```
type Selector = <S>(state: S) => unknown


interface Bundle<
  Name extends string,
  Selectors extends BundleSelectors<Record<string, any>>,
> {
  name: Name
  selectors: Selectors
}

type BundleInitializer = <
  Name extends string,
  Selectors extends BundleSelectors<Record<string, any>>,
>(
  content: {
    name: Name
    selectors: Selectors
  }
) => Bundle<Name, Selectors>


declare const Init: BundleInitializer

const bun = Init({
  name: "Foo", selectors: {
    wrongname: 'wrongtype',                 // CASE 1 (name incorrect, type incorrect)
    selectCorrectName: 'wrongtype',         // CASE 2 (name correct, type incorrect)
    wrongName: () => { },                   // CASE 3 (name incorrect, type correct)
    selectCorrectAll: () => { },            // CASE 4 (name correct, type correct)
  }
})
```

How are we suppose to define a BundleSelectors type to make sure all 4 cases are covered,
I've tried these two versions, each has its own problems but neither works fully

#### version 1

```
type BundleSelectors<T> = { [I in keyof T]: Selector }
```

#### version 2

type argument will be missing here, just add it if you want to check the types, its not used anymore but other types need to be updated to reflect

```
type BundleSelectors = Record<`select${string}`, Selector>
```

Both of these do not produced the desired effect.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXl81w) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Nevermind I am stupid, yes it does, write up the answere if you have the time please. The error message that is given is very bad though, not very intuitive

Comment: TS doesn't have a prohibition on excess properties in the type system (we don't have ["exact" types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)) so anything you try to do to force it to have one tends to produce "very bad, not very intuitive" error messages.  We don't have [custom error types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689).  You could try to fake one up like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO19rm) but I don't know if it meets your needs.  Should I do that in the answer or not bother?

Comment: Absolutely, if you can, do it. Anything helps, as I am expecting juniors to be using this and any form of confusion avoidance is great. Btw was looking up the custom error messages and found a proposal for one, you are on it, haaha.

Comment: Oh i see you actually menioned the very same, let me ask you then, in this answer you posted I've seen you use an interface with `__msg` is that some special key or did you just annote it that way. Also why is the custom message that you parsed there not appear on the errors, is it not suppose to, is the purpose to look at the type itself?

Comment: Did you forget me? :'(

Comment: No, sometimes I need to eat, work, sleep, etc., so occasionally I need to leave SO for a few hours.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: ^ Different versions of TS format errors different ways.  It used to be you'd see the offending `__msg` property in the error message, but now it seems to be suppressed (probably to make the error less wordy).  I changed it to just a string in my answer, but really without a native `Invalid`-like type, anything we do will just be a workaround.

Comment: Sorry if that came across wrong, didn't meant to be rude. Thanks for all the time and effort you put into helping this community, I've been assisted by your answers on several occasions where I had no answer for a long time. The detail you go into is greatly appriciated. Once again, appologies if I sounded ungrateful, was not the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to define `BundleInitializer` so that the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter corresponding to `selectors` is recursively [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) so that any property key that doesn't match `` `select${string}` `` is rejected in some way.  That would involve [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the type so that properties with good keys have type `Selector`, while those with bad keys have a type like [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) which is not compatible with any value likely to be passed in.  Let's call that type `BadKey<K>` which takes a key of type `K` and produces an incompatible type.

Then `BundleInitializer` would be defined as

```
type BundleInitializer = <
  N extends string,
  S extends { [K in keyof S]: K extends `select${string}` ? Selector : BadKey<K> }
>(content: { name: N; selectors: S }) => Bundle<N, S>
```

and you'd get the desired behavior:

```
const bun = Init({
  name: "Foo", selectors: {
    wrongname: 'wrongtype',                 // error
    selectCorrectName: 'wrongtype',         // error
    wrongName: () => { },                   // error
    selectCorrectAll: () => { },            // okay
  }
})
```

---

So all that remains is defining `BadKey`.  We can trivially define it as `never`,

```
type BadKey<K extends PropertyKey> = never;
```

but then the error message just says that the property isn't `never` as expected, which is confusing.  Ideally TypeScript would provide an "invalid" type whose type is `never`-like but which provides a user-friendly error message, but TypeScript doesn't currently have such a facility.  There's an open feature request for it at [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689).  If it existed maybe we could write

```
type BadKey<K extends PropertyKey> = Invalid<
  `You provided a key of "${Exclude<K, symbol>}" \
  but the keys all need to be of the form \`select${string}\``
>;
```

but it doesn't.  For now, all we can do is something like

```
type BadKey<K extends PropertyKey> = `You provided a key of "${Exclude<K, symbol>}" \
  but the keys all need to be of the form \`select${string}\``;
```

and rely on the fact that whatever the property value passed in is very unlikely to be that error string.  So we get errors like:

```
Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 
  '`You provided a key of "wrongName" but the keys all 
  need to be of the form \`select${string}\``'.(2322)
```

which is hopefully enough for people to understand what to do.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhA2EDGwD2AnKBeKAeGAfABQDOwAhsBAFywCU2BUArgHYDWrqA7qwFB8AlqyroAZuSTQAQmwAmiXHyhQAclAgAPKqzkkoZdMIDmAGmWxzTAN4XW5ALY01FkgmRp0JWjD4BfAVBIKGlyOQBpCBBccI1tCF19AAV0VEh0UEiQJhwAAwBNVGYoMFSAN0E5CDkocih2KKhUMSgAIgASawBRTSR4ZiqY0wMQBwAjVHgCP1aoAB0LMeZgKGAAC2gGkH1yeHgoVghq1dQoMehm1Y2oMQwHedy3RBROwxM-OdzcgG4BPiCZPJEABJViCYCCXaCABeEEwOCUKnUWh0egMwCMrDMFhgcVR+msUAA2rFhPUopcYABdWixFEJNGPdwvaxvLF+XJQAD8sGZnigtFCESiMSYAWISFQIgSwFohPsTloqm+Bj5GG8sCgfgYWCYsl0ilUw0IfyqfXI6GgktYZCgoPBgqBEHtEKhsPQAmttqWrGwdrBwCIthUCucrQAYqhUK1hk8POq5RYVNxUljQ7QAOQpqXGAEZ4YqQtF4sqAD0pagAGEAIIwLpQACMUCIoagwkl6EtKGGALbrA7XeAdCTquewErGEHqkczizqdz4Ag+ZLhfLVdr9YATM3WwOPD3F329yhh0Xs1jp4rmzqbFqCyuH2WKzW61AAMw7mdHyf71aH49DiOcYoBOnYeNWey0EQN5QISfj3o+a4vvWAAsn5OFAAEHsEAGnlq-jDnwQA)

Comment: As always, thorough and straight to the point.  Will try to implement this now. Thanks once again.

Comment: One more thing, this is a minute detail but, any way to prevent a key of exactly `select` from being valid, because technically it is valid so long as the "string" part of that conditional type is an empty string.

Comment: I've added another conditional to the mapping to check for exactly "select" and BadKey-ed if it was the case, thanks for all the help, its working as intended

Comment: I've hit a dead end when trying to use these types with mapped types as the constraints implemented for the error handling mess with the resulting types. Do you have any idea how to avoid that, or maybe the right question would be, how does one use a mapped tuple type, and then still keep the "general shape" of what was mapped to pass around to functions?